# Field inclusion in an Attestation Form

Tags: attestations

All,

I'm very new to this, so if I'm blatantly missing something obvious, my apologies.

A request from my manager is to include relevant Entities to a 'header' section of an Attestation form.

These would include the **Control Objective** Name, the Description, and possible other fields on the control objective page itself.  The outcome for this is to help identify to the person filling out the attestation the control they are validating.  I understand that this should be obvious... however my manager has this request.

I'm working from an existing form, which someone also put a jpg as a header.  I've never figured out how they did that.  Any insight on that would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

I went through the includes on the left of the attestation designer, none of those were able to pull in the data that has been requested.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.